# Non-ARC library object sent to ARC code. Overreleased?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

A non-ARC precompiled static library I'm using is sending my ARC app "event" NSObjects on my main thread, that it has placed in the main-thread's autorelease pool. My app acts on the event object in a handler function, but doesn't retain or release it, and doesn't use it again.

With Zombies on, I am occasionally getting a break when the main event loop drains the top level autorelease pool and one of these event NSObjects is being deallocated. It smells like ARC has already released the event object (perhaps when it went out of scope in my handler) and then the main event loop releases it again.

Is this a plausible theory, or is this impossible and I have another bug?

If it is possible, what can I do in my app to prevent this?

Comment: Are there multiple threads?

Comment: Errors when the retain count gets miscalculated due to an ARC/non-ARC mismatch should either always happen, or not happen at all. I strongly doubt that that is what is going on.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple threads, but all the action here takes place on the main thread.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Yes, I agree with your point. Then it does point to something other than an arc/non-arc mismatch.

Comment: The right way to figure this out is to use the Zombies instrument not just to learn of the fact of the message being sent to a deallocated object but to then examine the history of allocating, retains, releases, and deallocation for that object. Analysis of that history should reveal which code is releasing the object when it wasn't entitled to.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, the autorelease works as it should - the function has autoreleased the object, meaning that you can use it but then it's released at the end of the auto release pool.

By default you use autorelease pool in the main loop. However nothing stops you from wrapping your call into `@autorelease` block and checking that the object is released at the correct time.